# Error: rxjs/Subject"' has no exported member 'Subject'

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have this code:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
```

After importing this, I get the error

> rxjs/Subject" has no exported member 'Subject'.

I am not able to resolve this.
Could anybody suggest a solution?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

It looks you use RxJS v6. In v6, the way you import resources has been made much more easy. Your import should be like the following:

```
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';
```

For more details read the [migration guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md).

Comment: thank you!!   import { Subscription } from 'rxjs'; same for this also

Comment: same fo this : @Lucifer import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';